# Illegal instruction signal for arrow parquet. How to build with Conan without AVX2

Tags: c++, avx2, conan, apache-arrow

I'm using conan to build a library that uses arrow parquet. I built arrow myself because I couldn't find versions in conan center that included parquet:

In my conanfile.txt

```
[options]
arrow:shared=True  # I tried both shared and static
arrow:parquet=True
arrow:with_snappy=True
```

```
conan install .. --build=arrow
```

It builds and executes properly in my machine, but fails the tests in the Jenkins server with

```
 SIGILL - Illegal instruction signal
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058325/program-received-signal-sigill-illegal-instruction) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273849/illegal-instruction-on-avx-with-intel-core-i7) posts, it seems like there could be an architecture conflict. And indeed, there are differences:

Jenkins server

```
AVX supported
AVX2 not supported
```

my computer

```
AVX supported
AVX2 supported
```

Furthermore, the arrow code has optimizations up to the avx level. For example, in byte_stream_split.h:

```
#if defined(ARROW_HAVE_AVX2)
template <typename T>
void ByteStreamSplitDecodeAvx2(const uint8_t* data, int64_t num_values, int64_t stride,
                               T* out)
// Code
```

Since I didn't add support for AVX2, how do I tell conan to build arrow without AVX2 support, or whatever the minimum common configuration might be?

Or is there something entirely different I should be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In arrow, the level of SIMD instructions used is controlled by these [cmake options](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/9aaf61c044189d4d15bd145380fb4e2a2a65138f/cpp/cmake_modules/DefineOptions.cmake#L113)

```
  define_option_string(ARROW_SIMD_LEVEL
                       "Compile-time SIMD optimization level"
                       "SSE4_2" # default to SSE4.2
                       "NONE"
                       "SSE4_2"
                       "AVX2"
                       "AVX512")

  define_option_string(ARROW_RUNTIME_SIMD_LEVEL
                       "Max runtime SIMD optimization level"
                       "MAX" # default to max supported by compiler
                       "NONE"
                       "SSE4_2"
                       "AVX2"
                       "AVX512"
                       "MAX")
```

This option is used [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/ac050c6c583535c2f60063d8b341568b52170485/cpp/cmake_modules/SetupCxxFlags.cmake#L89), to check whether or not to pass in the preprocessor definitions

```
  if(CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX2 AND ARROW_RUNTIME_SIMD_LEVEL MATCHES "^(AVX2|AVX512|MAX)$")
    set(ARROW_HAVE_RUNTIME_AVX2 ON)
    add_definitions(-DARROW_HAVE_RUNTIME_AVX2 -DARROW_HAVE_RUNTIME_BMI2)
  endif()
```

You can specify this cmake option, `ARROW_SIMD_LEVEL` and `ARROW_RUNTIME_SIMD_LEVEL` via the cmake generator when you run cmake. If that doesn't work, it means arrow doesn't yet support it as a cmake config through conan, so you might need to alter your build flow to be able to manually run cmake

Comment: Thanks. It seemed like setting ARROW_RUNTIME_SIMD_LEVEL  as an environment variable or conan line option should do the trick, but it doesn't. I'll need to investigate even more about how conan sends options to cmake.

Comment: Hi! If you have a look at the recipe for `arrow` package (https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/arrow/all/conanfile.py), you can see that we list the options as attributes (`options` and `default_options`) and then we add the value to the proper CMake variable using `self._cmake.definitions["..."] = <value>`. 

I encourage you to contribute the changes via pull-request.

Comment: It seems that the defaults have changed since this post was written. In Arrow 9.0.0, `ARROW_SIMD_LEVEL` defaults to `DEFAULT` which does the right thing on ARM as well: [source](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/ea6875fd2a3ac66547a9a33c5506da94f3ff07f2/cpp/cmake_modules/DefineOptions.cmake#L122). `DEFAULT` should probably be used in place of `SSE4_2` or `NONE` for most use cases.